# 以下のコードと同じような出力をint 型のみで表現する。

Tags: java

以下のコードは、int型2つと、Stringで表現していますが、同じような出力結果を表現したいとき、この `r` をint (引数がすべてint型)で書くとするとどのようなコードで表現できますか?

```
public class Partitions {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        partition(7, 7, "");
    }

    public static void partition(int i, int n, String r) {
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("{" + r + "}");
            return;
        }

        /*
           for (int j = Math.min(i, n);j >= 1;j--) {
           partition(j, n - j, j + (r.isEmpty()?"":",")+r);
           }

         */

        if( i<n ){
            for( int j=i ;j>=1;j--){
                partition( j,n-j,j+(r.isEmpty()?"":",")+r);
            }
        }else{
            for (int j = n;j >= 1;j--) {
                partition(j, n - j, j + (r.isEmpty()?"":",")+r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int`型変数をstackに見立てるのはどうでしょうか。

```java
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Stream.Builder;

public class Partitions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        partition(7, 7, 0);
    }

    public static void partition(int i, int n, int r) {
        if (n == 0) {
            write(r);
            return;
        }

        if (i < n) {
            for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
                partition(j, n - j, push(r, j));
            }
        } else {
            for (int j = n; j >= 1; j--) {
                partition(j, n - j, push(r, j));
            }
        }
    }

    static void write(int r) {
        String numbers = stream(r).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        System.out.println("{" + numbers + "}");
    }

    static int push(int r, int j) {
        return (r << 3) | j;
    }

    static Stream<Integer> stream(int r) {
        Builder<Integer> ret = Stream.builder();
        while (r > 0) {
            int v = r & 0x7;
            ret.add(v);
            r = r >>> 3;
        }
        return ret.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

引数 `r` は必要ないでしょう。

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Partitions {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    partition(7, 7).forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  public static List<List<Integer>> partition(int i, int n) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    if (n == 0) {
      result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
      return result;
    }

    for (int j = Math.min(i, n);j > 0;j--) {
      for (List<Integer> row: partition(j, n - j)) {
        row.add(j); result.add(row);
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}

// 実行結果
[7]
[1, 6]
[2, 5]
[1, 1, 5]
[3, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 1, 1, 4]
[1, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```